# JavaScript Filter Func: filter on multiple conditions (either could be true)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, filter, filtering

Might be something super simple that I am over looking.

I have an array of objects that contains some info. Based on user action, I'd like to filter out some objects;

```
let arr = [
 {'num': 1, 'name': 'joe'},
 {'num': 2, 'name': 'jane'},
 {'num': 3, 'name': 'john'},
 {'num': 3, 'name': 'johnny'},
]
```

what I've tried

```
 function filterArr(arr) {
  return arr.filter(obj => {
    if(obj.num && obj.num !== 1) {
      return obj;
    }
    if(obj.num && obj.num !== 3) {
     return obj;
    }
  })
}
```

when i run filterArr, I am returned back the original array, but the expected result should be just **{'num': 2, 'name': 'jane'},,**. I can console.log inside both of the nested condition.

Any help of filtering array based on 1 of 2 conditions being true would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Every single `num` will pass *either* of your `if` conditions because there isn't a number in the universe which is equal to 1 and 3 at the same time**. You can just chain the `&&` condition inside the `filter` to check for all of them:

```js
let arr = [
 {'num': 1, 'name': 'joe'},
 {'num': 2, 'name': 'jane'},
 {'num': 3, 'name': 'john'},
 {'num': 3, 'name': 'johnny'},
]

let filtered = arr.filter(a => a.num && a.num !== 3 && a.num !== 1)

console.log(filtered)
```

(**Unless it's `0`, `null`, `undefined` or any of the [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values of course. In which case they will fail the `obj.num` condition of both `if`s)

Answer (score 2):

**Let's understand the problem first**.

so you had two conditions one checks for not equal to `1` and other checks for not equal to `3` so for example if `num = 1` first one fails but second one still pass so eventually you're returning `true` in every case.

***You need to check both the condition in single if statement.***

```js
let arr = [{'num': 1, 'name': 'joe'},{'num': 2, 'name': 'jane'},{'num': 3, 'name': 'john'},{'num': 3, 'name': 'johnny'},]

function filterArr(arr) {
  return arr.filter(obj => obj.num !== 1 && obj.num!=3)
}

console.log(filterArr(arr))
```

Comment: yea that makes sense. I was over thinking this and didn't adjust my condition. Thank you for your answer and explanation.